# My sql query for selecting specified data from table

Tags: php, mysql, select, limit

I have counter $i in my php page , so i want to get the next 15 records right from that $ith row. I am just using the below query bt it is returning empty output. I have plenty of records in db though

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE @ROWNUM > '$i' LIMIT 15
```

Comment: why dont you use offset with limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to show 15 rows starting from $i ?

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT $i,15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a query as

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKS LIMIT $i, 15;
```

Check this link [**MySQL SELECT with LIMIT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Comment: change it to SELECT * FROM BOOKS LIMIT $i, 15;

Comment: Changed as you have specified